# How do I add validation to ngModelCtrl from input field inside directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive and want to use the validators from an input field used inside this directive template. Is there a way to extend ngModelCtrl validators with the input validators?

This is my directive:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .directive('myUrl', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: ['ngModel', '^form'],
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: '/components/url/my-url.html',
      scope: {},
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
        var ngModelCtrl = ctrls[0];
        var formCtrl = ctrls[1];
        scope.formField = ngModelCtrl;

        // Scope data vars
        scope.url = '';

        // Watchers
        scope.$watch('url', function(newValue) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
        });

        // Validators
        var inputValidators = formCtrl['my-url'].$validators;
        ngModelCtrl.$validators = angular.copy(inputValidators);

        // Custom render
        ngModelCtrl.$render = customRender;

        function customRender() {
          scope.url = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

This is my view:

```
    <div>
      <label>My URL</label>\
      <input type="url" name="my-url" placeholder="http://" ng-model="url">
      <div ng-messages="formField.$error" ng-show="formField.$invalid">
        <span ng-message="url">Invalid URL.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a fiddle with this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/bsmaniotto/gzLmy1op/

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Just realized that the problem is not on binding the `input[url]` validators to my custom directive `ngModelCtrl`'s validators. The `input[url]` element is being validated and when an invalid input is entered the `$modelValue` is not set, and therefore, for my custom directive it is as nothing is inputted.

Answer (score 0):

input validation is pretty easy in angular if you're using a controller. you can add:

ui-event: {keyup: 'controller.validationFunctionName(whatever)'}

Just fill in 'whatever' with the text in your input field and every time a key is let go it will check your validation function

If you want it to display an error beneath it just create another div that has an ng-if= to the result of that keyup function

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but `ngModelCtrl` already does that for us. I rather keep using its validators pipeline, just want to manually add the default `input[url]` validator inside the directive to the `ngModelCtrl` pipeline (as you can see on the fiddle I added).